# Why doesnt my webpage refresh when calling RedirectToAction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I'm currently developing a webpage which has a table with some table data, each row of table data has a button which is responsible of starting a process, and when I click one of the buttons, it fires an ajax call. Once the ajax call finishes, it then updates something on the webpage, this "something" is a span element, it updates the class and the text.

However if I refresh the page manually in between the process of me clicking the button when it fires the ajax call and it finishing, it wont update.

Let' me explain this with some code.

I have this button, which invokes the ajax call when clicked

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-icon waves-effect waves-light btn-success" onclick="@("StartProcess('"+model.ProcessName+"')")"> <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> </button>
```

The Ajax call looks like this

```
 function StartProcess(ProcessName) {

        var dataPost = { processName: ProcessName};
        $.ajax({
            data: dataPost,
            url: '@Url.Action("Start", "Dashboard")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            beforeSend: function () {
                // Handle the beforeSend event
                $("#" + ProcessName).removeClass("badge-danger").addClass("badge-info").html("Starting");
            },
            success: function (redirect) {
                // Handle the complete event
                window.location = redirect;
                $("#" + ProcessName).removeClass("badge-info").addClass("badge-success").html("Online");


            },
            error: function() {
                //AJAX request not completed
                $("#" + ProcessName).removeClass("badge-info").addClass("badge-danger").html("Error");
    }
            // ......
        });
    };
```

And what this does, is that it makes a request to a `IActionResult` on the back-end which does run perfectly.
Here is what it looks like, keep in mind that **it reaches the RedirectToAction every single time** even if I refresh or not.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Start(string ProcessName)
        {
            ProcessFactory.StartProcess(ProcessName, _user);
            while (ProcessFactory.ServerFlag == null)
            {
                //Stalling until "ProcessFactory.StartProcess" has finished

            }

            //It reaches this no matter what
            if (ProcessFactory.ServerFlag == "Online")
            {
                Debug.Print("===========ONLINE============");
                Response.StatusCode = 200;

                //It reaches this no matter what
                return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
            }
            else if (ProcessFactory.ServerFlag == "Already running")
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 200;
                return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
            }
            else if (ProcessFactory.ServerFlag == "Error")
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 401;
                return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
        }
```

Here is the issue that I am facing, when I click start and I just let it run without refreshing the page, it works just fine, it updates the element without any issues.

If however I refresh the browser after I click the start button, while it inside the while loop, it finishes the exact same way by hitting the **RedirectToAction** but this time it doesnt refresh the browser, it doesnt even invoke the "Dashboard" IActionResult. I tried putting a breakpoint inside it before refreshing the page, and it hit it, but when I tried it again, but this time refreshing the page, it didn't hit the breakpoint. And keep in mind that **it reaches the RedirectToAction every single time** inside one of the if statements, no matter what, even if I refresh or not.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Dashboard()
        {
            ProcessFactory.LoadProcesses(_user);

            //Load all processes
            var model = ProcessFactory.LoadProcesses(_user);

            return View(model);
        }
```

Is this a case of losing context or what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a `RedirectToAction()` (equivalent of a 302) to JavaScript and it doesn't know how to handle that.  I see you're trying to manually set the response code but the easiest solution would be to simply change your what you're returning to a URL.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Start(string ProcessName)
{
    ProcessFactory.StartProcess(ProcessName, _user);
    //[....lots of stuff]
    return Json(Url.Action("Dashboard", "Dashboard"));
}
```

On your JavaScript, change return type to JSON.  Arguably you could return a string from your controller without wrapping in JSON but this allows you to return more data in the future if you so choose (by simply adding more to the JSON response)

```
function StartProcess(ProcessName) {

    var dataPost = { processName: ProcessName};
    $.ajax({
        data: dataPost,
        url: '@Url.Action("Start", "Dashboard")',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            // Handle the beforeSend event
            $("#" + ProcessName).removeClass("badge-danger").addClass("badge-info").html("Starting");
        },
        success: function (redirect) {
            // Handle the complete event
            window.location = redirect;
            //changing any part of the UI is redundant here as you are redirecting
            //the browser window
        },
        error: function() {
            //AJAX request not completed
            $("#" + ProcessName).removeClass("badge-info").addClass("badge-danger").html("Error");
}
        // ......
 });
};
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but it still doesn't update if I refresh in between the time of me clicking the button and waiting for the process to start, it's going to be stuck on "Starting" until I manually refresh after it finishes, that only happens if I refresh the page manually before it finishes. If I let it run, it will work just fine.

Comment: (It's almost as if the ajax loses context if I manually refresh it after clicking start